# Cause of SHM of liquid-column in V-tube

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Suppose there is a v-shaped tube filled with water. The left limb is at $\theta_1$ & the right limb is at $\theta_2$ with the horizontal base. Initially, the level of water in both the columns are same.If the water is depressed by $x$ in one limb, it will rise by $x$ in the other limb & will undergo SHM (as my book says). Now, for  SHM to occur, there must be a restoring force.   My book mentions that this is provided by **hydrostatic pressure difference** & jots down a formula $$F_R = -(\Delta P) A = -\rho gA(\sin\theta_1 + \sin\theta_2)x$$, where $\rho$ is the density of water & $A$ is the cross-section of the columns. I want to know how the formula has been derived; I'm unable to conceive it. Also I do want to know how **hydrostatic pressure difference** plays the role of restoring force.

Comment: Hydrostatic pressure difference drives the fluid from where the level is higher to where it is lower, and also this pressure difference increases as level difference increases. These are just the characteristics required of a restoring force (compare with what a spring does).

Answer (score 1):

If liquid rises in right column by $x$, corresponding height gained will be $x \sin(\theta_2)$.

If liquid in left column goes down by $x$, corresponding vertical depth will be $x \sin(\theta_1)$.

Total height difference will be sum of above.

We know Pressure = height $\times$ density $\times$ gravity